# How to use join on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine that I have some  elasticsearch indexes. I'm fetching them via a key. For example, that key is a city. As an example, fetching all users date from Maribor. My aim is fetching users from maribor and get  user's event date and fetching from Ljubljana and get same user's event date and compare them. How can i do this ? For being clear, it is same with join method in traditional db. I already checked aggregations but i couldn't solve it. Can someone give an example of query dsl ?

**As a scenario,**

```
{
    "username" : "marko"
    "city" : "maribor"
    "event-date": "22-02-2020"
    "another-city" : "empty"
    ....
}

{
    "username" : "marko"
    "city" : "ljubljana"
    "event-date": "22-02-2020"
    "another-city" : "empty"
    ....
}

{
    "username" : "slvia"
    "city" : "ljubljana"
    "event-date": "22-02-2020"
    ....
}
```

**I want to fetch only username is "marko" and city "ljubljana" or "maribor" and event-date "22-02-2020".
If username = "marko" city "ljubljana" set anothercity second one's city. I mean set "another-city": maribor,
else if username = "marko" city "maribor" set anothercity first one's. I mean set "another-city" : ljubljana. Likewise cross match data**

Thanks for answering

Comment: can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Comment: @ESCoder, first of all thanks for answering you always help. I ve edited the question.